# How do I return a relation in RedisGraph?

Tags: redisgraph

Using RedisGraph, I'd like for a QUERY to RETURN a relation's type.

An example query:

`MATCH (n1:Entity { id: "foo" }) MATCH (n2:Entity2 { id: "bar" }) CREATE (n1)-[r:areFriends]->(n2) RETURN *`

Unfortunately, the returned value only includes `n1` and `n2`, but not `r`.

The returned record contains the following:

`Record {
  _header: [ 'n1.id', 'n1.name', 'n2.id', 'n2.name' ]`

This is compliant with my schema, yet `r` is notoriously missing there.

How can I get RETURN to return the relation?

OpenCypher supports syntax like:

`RETURN n1, n2, type(r)` but this doesn't seem to work in RedisGraph.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

PR just merged to MASTER

```
127.0.0.1:6379> GRAPH.QUERY G "create (:Entity {id:'foo'}), (:Entity {id:'bar'})"
1) (empty list or set)
2) 1) "Labels added: 1"
   2) "Nodes created: 2"
   3) "Properties set: 2"
   4) "Query internal execution time: 0.536000 milliseconds"

127.0.0.1:6379> GRAPH.QUERY G "MATCH (n1:Entity {id:'foo'}), (n2:Entity {id:'bar'}) CREATE (n1)-[r:areFriends]->(n2) RETURN n1,n2,TYPE(r)"
1) 1) 1) "n1.id"
      2) "n2.id"
      3) "TYPE(r)"
   2) 1) "foo"
      2) "bar"
      3) "areFriends"
2) 1) "Relationships created: 1"
   2) "Query internal execution time: 0.409000 milliseconds"
```

Please note, this change will be part of version 1.0.12

Until that version is released, you can either build from source or use docker image redislabs/redisgraph:edge

Answer (score 1):

Currently RedisGraph doesn't support mixing the CREATE and RETURN clauses, although this work is in the making and should be available within a couple of days.

Comment: Thanks for making a PR. For other's reference: https://github.com/RedisLabsModules/RedisGraph/pull/327